# Plotting excel data using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I want to plot data in the following excel file using pandas package in python [image: excel data spreadsheet]. I want to plot column B vs Column C, and column D vs Column E, column F vs Column G and column H vs Column I without the need to convert the spreadsheet to a csv or txt file. Here is my code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_name = 'datafile.xlsx'
df =  pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=0, usecols="B:C""D:E""F:G""H:I")

#ARRAYS to store data
x_data =[]
y_data = []


# Get the series of the chart column from the dataframe data.
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    column = i +1
    x_data.append(int(column[1]))
```

Comment: have so far tried to import read the data with the `df =  pd.read_excel()` command but ii want a have a loop where i get individual column data but am stuck

Comment: first use `df = pd.read_excel(path)` then `df.plot(x='B', y='C')`

Comment: I don't think that can work. tried it but getting an error

Comment: Your syntax for `usecols` is incorrect. Try `usecols="B,C,D,E,F,G,H:I"` or `usecols="["B:C","D:E","F:G","H:I"]`. Also, `column` is an integer but you're indexing it like so `column[1]`. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tonikami04 I can confirm it does work. Please report the error you get

Comment: `KeyError: 'B'` that is what am getting

Comment: If you get that error when plotting is because you did not assign column names when reading the excel. see Jon Nir answer to see how

Answer (score 2):

You have a few syntax problems, I would recommend reading the read_excel [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). Also, if you want to plot the DataFrame and actually visualize the graph, you need to import matplotlib also.

In order to load the DF correctly from the excel, you need to specify a list of **column-number** (0-indexed) you want to load. So, if you want to load columns B-I, you need to specify usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. I can see from you screen-shot that you don't have column-header. pd will use the 1st row as header unless you specify otherwise, causing you to "lose" the first row of data. Moreover, if you want to name the columns differently, you need to specify so when you create the DF.
So your read_excel line should be:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=None, usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], names=['B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','G','H','I'])
```

now, if you want to create a pd.Serie for your x/y axis, it is very easy:

```
X = df['B']
Y = df['C']
```

Note these are pandas Serie objects, not arrays (I'm assuming you mean a list/tuple, as python doesn't have arrays as a generic-type). You can easily cast a pd.Serie object to a different type:

```
x_list = list(X)
y_tuple = tuple(Y)
```

That being said, if what you want is to **plot** those 2 columns, you can use the DF's plotting method and specify your axes, like [joaquin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308903/joaquin) said:

```
df.plot(x='B', y='C')
plt.show()
```